# Изменить вид массива php

Tags: php

Есть массив заказов, где place_amount это количество заказов, а второе это его дата:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [place_amount] => 2
            [order_date] => 2022-11-09 13:53:29
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [place_amount] => 1
            [order_date] => 2022-11-11 17:54:52
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [place_amount] => 3
            [order_date] => 2022-11-12 12:30:46
        )
)
```

Нужно чтобы было вида:

```
Array
(
    [2] => 2022-11-09 13:53:29
    [1] => 2022-11-11 17:54:52
    [2] => 2022-11-12 12:30:46
)
```

И третий вариант, вывести через запятую количество заказов и аналогично даты заказов.
В интернете нашёл что раскладывается через implode(',', $result), но выдаёт ошибку о неправильно переданных аргументах.

Comment: не будет как хотите ключи массива уникальны. `implode` вообще какой то пальцем в небо, и не попали, очевидно.

Comment: @teran Изначально делаю выборку данных из базы данных, для построения графика. Где будет отображаться количество покупок по дням.

Comment: вот и посчитайте количество покупок по дням прям в запросе. зачем это тащить на пхп? У вас может быт тысяча покупок за день и график на месяц. В итоге вместо отправки 30 значений вы вытащите на бэк 30тыс, еще и мудрить будете потом как это сделать. Хотя для запроса в БД надо дописать всего 30 символов и получить готовый результат.

Comment: Это да, так и планировал изначально, но собираю скрипт по гайдам из интернета, где все как один считают и складывают значения отдельно после запроса. Подставляя суммы заказов ко дням.

Comment: Но и в запросе я же не могу сложить количество заказов по дням месяца и т.д. И как Вы сказали, ключи массива должны быть уникальны, таким образом я могу вложить туда order_id что будет уникальным. Либо я что то не догоняю.

Comment: почему не можете сложить в запросе? Вы лучше покажите, что у вас есть за данные, и какой результат хотите получить на выходе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$a = array(
  array(
    'id' => 5698,
    'first_name' => 'Peter',
    'last_name' => 'Griffin',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 4767,
    'first_name' => 'Ben',
    'last_name' => 'Smith',
  ),
  array(
    'id' => 3809,
    'first_name' => 'Joe',
    'last_name' => 'Doe',
  )
);

$first_name = array_column($a, 'last_name');

Array
(
  [0] => Griffin
  [1] => Smith
  [2] => Doe
)
```

Здесь есть примеры https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_column.asp

Answer (score 0):

1. Ключи должны быть уникальными
2. Нужно понять для чего нужна такая структура массива? Может у вас не правильное представление того что вам нужно?
3. Со структурой которая у вас изначально, очень легко работать, а вот что вы собираетесь делать с массивом, который хотите получить, не понятно.

Опишите более подробно, что в дальнейшем должно происходить с массивом.

Comment: Весь замысел уже описал на другом форуме: [https://www.cyberforum.ru/php-beginners/thread3052091.html]